# Why my link is jammed up against top border in browser?

Tags: html, css

Why my link is jammed up against top border in browser?

`box-sizing: border-box;` don't change anything

```css
a {
  background-color: #405cf5;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="/posts">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Margins don't apply to inline elements, and with padding only the left and right property will push other elements. Change your link (inline by default) to have a display of inline-block and it will move according to the margin and padding you gave it:

```css
a {
  background-color: #405cf5;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="/posts">Back</a>
```